# invalid argument error on [NSTimer invalidate]

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am using the following code for a NSTimer:

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveRect) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and inside the moveRect function, I am using the following to stop the timer:

```
[timer invalidate]
```

Usually, it works fine..However once in a while I get an exception saying invalid argument...

Can anyone kindly tell me what I am missing here ? Thanks !

Edit: getting "EXEC_BAD_ACCESS" ..any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalidate the timer and then call:

```
timer = nil;
```

Comment: added the code..thanks for the hint..will let you know if it works or not...I didnt downvote.so not sure why !